# QR code with custom background

Tags: image-editing, barcodes

I'm trying to make a QR code design like this one that I found on the web, but I have no clue on how to make it, and the code seems to be scan-able as well. (it's not just a fake code)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a QR generator and download the svg?

Comment: Why would this be a fake code?

Comment: i haven't tried svg,i downloaded it in png format and tried putting a layer mask with the picture i want instead of the black part of the code in Photoshop but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment it seems that you are very close! The QR code should be used as mask on the background image, not the other way around.

A mask is a grayscale image. Where the mask is white it will allow the image to shine through, where it's black the image will become transparent.

Here is a recipe:

- Open up the background image ("Mona Lisa" in your example).
- Drag and drop the QR code image to the document.
- Resize and position the QR code to your liking.
- Create a white layer beneath the QR code (covering the background).
- Press `Ctrl+A`/`Cmd+A` to select all.
- Press `Shift+Ctrl+C`/`Shift+Cmd+C` to copy merged.
- Turn off the QR code and the white background.
- Select the background layer and create a mask.
- `Alt+click` the mask to enter "mask mode".
- Press `Ctrl+V`/`Cmd+V` to paste in the QR code.
- Press `Ctrl+D`/`Cmd+D` to deselect all.
- Press `Ctrl+I`/`Cmd+I` to invert the mask.
- `Click` the background layer thumbnail to return to "normal mode".